# Problem: light passing through metal surface

Tags: modeling

I've modeled a ceiling lamp. Would anyone be able to explain how to solve the problem of the light passing through the material? Thanks

[image: light off]

[image: light on]

[image: material node]

[image: wireframe]

[image: difference]

Comment: Check the normals for the object. Enter edit mode and press Ctrl + N to make normals consistent.

Comment: I tried but does not solve the problem, other solutions?

Comment: I can't really see where the light is passing through. Can I ask you to update your question where you highlight your problem and, if needed, add the blender file?

Comment: Of course, I added an image to the original post where you can see the difference

.blend file: http://www.filedropper.com/lampadari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point lamp was larger than the mesh that contained it, reducing the size of the lamp I solve the problem.

Thank you all

Comment: ..and thanks for bothering to answer your own question

Comment: @cegaton Get it. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

To the segment the light is passing through, use a SOLIDIFY modifier. Put some thickness on it. Light will not pass.

Thank you for your consideration to vote me as the answer by clicking to the left :the icon with a check mark and upvote this answer.

BFCT_Schiller

Comment: The modifier is already present, but does not solve the problem.